# How much the pronoun "it", or "them" is common in formal writing

Tags: pronouns, style

I don't know why, but somehow I don't like "it" or "them" as a pronoun in a formal writing (e.g. in a scientific article)

Is it just my style or is it common?
specially for the prepositional phrases with "it" or "them". for example (in it, for it, by it, using it, ...)

> After creating a node we can choose a parent for **it** from the list ...
>
> After creating a node we can choose a parent for **this node** from the list ...

The later also has repetition! Maybe another alternative exists!

I thought when the sentence gets long, the reader maybe lost the reference of "it" or "them" and someway repeating something is helpful.

For example it was my sentence

> To restrict this context to a specific scope within the page, we can choose a “Parent context” **for it** from the list of previously defined contexts (e.g. “Products”).

Comment: There is no reason to avoid using *it* in any register at all.

Comment: @StoneyB Maybe one reason that sometimes  I don't like `it` is the low stress of `it`, as it is said in http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/it-this.html

Comment: In this particular instance you could omit the reference altogether: "After creating a node we can choose a parent from the list"

Comment: @StoneyB Good, cause sometimes it looks like a redundant tail! let's cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule for avoiding *it*. However, as with all words, you should avoid repetition and make sure your text is readable. Your first sentence is perfectly fine. Just make sure you choose different words to refer to something. If you're talking about *Obama*, you shouldn't repeat the word *Obama* all the time. Instead, vary by using *the President of the US*, *the head of state*, *POTUS* or even words such as *the man*, *he*, *leader* and so on.

What follows is a bit more explanation on varying in word choice in texts by using referential words:

The word *it* as used in your sentence is what we call an **anaphor**. This means that it is a word referring back to something mentioned earlier in the text. The other two types of '*phor*' are the *cataphor* (referring to something mentioned after the cataphor itself) and the *exophor* (referring to something outside the text.

Now, anaphors in particular are used to avoid repetition of the same word in your text. You replace a mentioned word, phrase or entire clause with synonyms, pronouns or anything else that could possibly express the same meaning. Let me give you an example:

> - *I dropped my phone*. **It** broke.
> - *I sang a song*, and **that** was not appreciated by the audience.

Anaphors are used in order to keep a certain part of the text in the reader's mind. For example, if you introduce someone by name in the first paragraph of a text, you cannot all of a sudden refer to that person again using *he* or *she* after 100 lines of text if you did not continue on that subject and kept using anaphors to keep that person in your reader's mind. If you then want to talk about that person again, you could use for example:

> The person we talked about in the first paragraph.

The longer the distance between the *anaphor* and the *referent*, the more explicit you will have to be. The short example sentences I gave above could use *it* and *that*. This is because their referents were very close, meaning that not much explicitation is needed to bring the referent back tot he readers mind.

Other than anaphors, you can also use words that link the context in order to keep your text flowing:

> I dropped *my phone*. **Its screen** cracked. I now won't be able to access **my contacts**.

Though these words are not synonyms, they refer to each other. Without the first phrase, the second and third ones wouldn't make much sense. The words in bold in the second and third sentence remind the user that we are talking about *my phone* still.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer and guidance

Comment: Your explanation was enough, but just for another example I mentioned one of my own sentences in the question.

Comment: That sentence is fine. However, if by *choose X for something* you mean *assign X to something* I would go with the latter construction instead. It sounds more idiomatic.

Comment: Apart from these, maybe another reason is the `stress` which makes me sometimes prefer the noun over the pronoun, as it is in http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/it-this.html

Comment: The article you linked handles *pronouns*. Both *it* and *this* are pronouns. *This node* is a noun where *this* is a demonstrative determiner.

Comment: Yes but yet I think has more stress than `it`, in general.

Comment: Ah yes, for purposes of stressing things *this* is indeed better than *it*.

Answer (score 1):

Like StoneyB said, there is no reason to avoid using "it". Take your sentence for example:

> Is it just my style or is it common?

Avoiding "it", we would have:

> Is using the word "it" just my style or is using the word "it" common?

The second sentence, even though it's perfectly valid English, sounds awkward and forced.

Or take the previous sentence of this answer. To rewrite *it* (there *it* is again!) without an "it" we would have:

> The second sentence, even though the second sentence is perfectly valid English, sound awkward and forced.

Your writing will sound more natural and concise if you use "it".

Comment: True, but when the sentence gets long, I thought maybe the reader lost the reference of "it" or "them" and someway repeating something is helpful.

Comment: please consider the revision of my question, however its still mostly the same.

Comment: @Ahmad True, there is a balance. Not enough pronouns --> It feels awkward to repeat the noun too many times. Too many pronouns --> You can lose track of which pronoun refers to which. I'd say, just write what feels natural and then read it to yourself, or even to someone else. Even though we don't do proofreading here, a question like "Is it clear what the 'it' in this sentence refers to?" would be a great question for this site.